# Multipole Network Power Calculation

Tags: power, passive-networks, math, circuit-theory, resistive-load

How do we calculate the DC power consumption of a multipole resistive network, if we know the currents of all the poles (pins) and all the voltages between the poles?

Let's say for example, that we have a 4 pole. The first pole has a voltage of 10 V (to an arbitrary reference gnd) and an amperage of -1 A (1 A flows into the network through this pole). The second pole is 5 V and -4 A, the third is 3 V and +3 A, and the fourth is 1 V and +2 A. What is the dissipated power?

Is it even possible to calculate the power from the pole currents and voltages or we need the actual inner structure of the network?

Comment: If the voltage is measured directly between the pairs, the gnd is irrelevant. Then you add up all the sources and subtract all the loads to obtain the network losses dissipated. No power is missing.